# Is there such a thing as "inverse unrequited love"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

Is there such a thing as inverse unrequited love where someone loves you but you don't love yourself as much as they love you?

I'm thinking about a situation where it's like you're suffering from impostor syndrome in a relationship.

Does this phenomenon have a name?

Comment: You seemed to have named it. It is not an inversion of the relationship, it is about your relationship with yourself: self-loathing?

Comment: I don't feel as if self-loathing is precise enough. I feel as if the term needs to poignantly describe the interference it's causing in the relationship. Another reason self loathing doesn't describe it here is that you may feel indifferent towards yourself or feel as if you don't love yourself enough for the relationship. I like the term romantic impostor syndrome. But I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: "self loathing" is rather extreme. "insecurity" or "low self-esteem" would be much more common levels of self-doubt. I think the term "unworthy for love" is used idiomatically.

Comment: I like the term but it makes it sound like it's on purpose; an impostor does a thing on purpose.

Comment: actually, in the case you describe, it would be "~feeling~ unworthy for love"

Comment: You didnt say 'somebody loves you but *you don't love them* **and** you dont love yourself as much as they love you' did you? Inverse unrequited love is not the right descriptor, IMHO, as long as the love is being **requited** (reciprocated) -- we should all **be** so lucky, as the gentleman said.... No, it is something else, and I am not sure there is a pre-existing term for the situation you describe. Maybe you want to invent a new terminology but it sure shouldn't use 'unrequited' unless 'you' does not love 'them' who loves 'you'!